# Getting a property/field name using getter method of a pojo/java bean?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a below class and i need to get field name from getter method using java reflection.
Is it possible to get field name or property name using getter method?

```
class A {

    private String name;
    private String salary;

    // getter and setter methods
}
```

My questions is: can i get field/property name by getter method? If I use getName(), can I get name property? I need name property but not its value. Is it possible through java reflection?

Comment: if you get useful answer...you should accept it :)

Answer (score 21):

yes it's 100% possible..

```
public static String getFieldName(Method method)
{
    try
    {
        Class<?> clazz=method.getDeclaringClass();
        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz);  
        PropertyDescriptor[] props = info.getPropertyDescriptors();  
        for (PropertyDescriptor pd : props) 
        {  
            if(method.equals(pd.getWriteMethod()) || method.equals(pd.getReadMethod()))
            {
                System.out.println(pd.getDisplayName());
                return pd.getName();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IntrospectionException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}
```

Comment: how to send method as a parameter?? getFieldName(cls.getProperty()) will give value

Comment: If property name is different from taking out the "get" and decapitalize the rest then this won't work. For example if I have a getName() getter and the property is called _name or m_name, etc

Comment: If you have a field named `arg1` and the getter-method is named `getAge` (what could be argumented to be dirty but a 100% pojo-bean), this is not 100% possible anymore.

Comment: How to make getName is method to send as parameter to this method

Answer (score 15):

The [reflection-util](https://github.com/cronn/reflection-util) library provides a way to determine the property (name) in a type-safe manner.
For example by using the getter method:

```
String propertyName = PropertyUtils.getPropertyName(A.class, A::getSalary);
```

The value of `propertyName` would be `"salary"` in this case.

*Disclaimer*: I’m one of the authors of the [reflection-util](https://github.com/cronn/reflection-util) library.

Comment: Do not use reflection-util it utilize "unsafe"  via transient dependencies and can not work on jdk > 8.

Comment: @rumatoest: I’m not aware that reflection-util does not work on jdk > 8. Could you probably file an issue in the project?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [lombok's](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants) `@FieldNameConstants` annotation.

Annotate your class:

```
import lombok.experimental.FieldNameConstants;
import lombok.AccessLevel;

@FieldNameConstants
public class FieldNameConstantsExample {
  private final String name;
  private final int rank;
}
```

which produces following code on the background:

```
public class FieldNameConstantsExample {
  private final String name;
  private final int rank;
  
  public static final class Fields {
    public static final String name = "name";
    public static final String rank = "rank";
  }
}
```

So you can access property name in a following way:

```
FieldNameConstantsExample.Fields.name
```

which is string `"name"`

Comment: Its nice and clean approach if you use "lombok".

Answer (score 7):

You cannot inspect what code does by using reflection.

You can assume that a `getName()` method read a field called `name` and does nothing else.  However there is no requirement for it to so. e.g. the field name might be `m_name` or `_name` or `nameField` or not even be a field.

Answer (score 7):

You can

```
Field[] declaredFields = A.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field f:declaredFields){
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
```

Comment: this only gives a list of all fields, not the one associated with a getter.

Comment: @Adam for that you need to list all get methods and using that method you can get fileds

Comment: It's what the OP wanted. I don't think it's possible without the property descriptors.

Answer (score 7):

It's not exactly good enough to just remove the "get" or "is" prefix and lower case the first letter. For example, the appropriate bean name for getID would be ID and not iD.

The easiest way to get the bean name is to lop off the get or is prefix and then pass the result into [Introspector.decapitalize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html#decapitalize-java.lang.String-).

Here's a method I wrote to do this very thing:

```
private String getBeanName(String methodName)
{
    // Assume the method starts with either get or is.
    return Introspector.decapitalize(methodName.substring(methodName.startsWith("is") ? 2 : 3));
}
```

Comment: A variable named ID (and a getter named getID) doesn't follow Java Bean naming conventions.  Variable names should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @NamelessVoice, you are correct that variables should start with a lowercase letter. However, we're not talking about variables. We're talking about properties.

Please see section 8.8 of the Javabean standard: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf

Comment: My bad, I didn't know about this edge-case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If your bean's follow JavaBean conventions then you use reflection to get all the "get" and "is" methods and remove "get" or "is" prefixes from the retrieved method names and you have the field names.

*Update*

```
// Get the Class object associated with this class.
    MyClass myClass= new MyClass ();
    Class objClass= myClass.getClass();

    // Get the public methods associated with this class.
    Method[] methods = objClass.getMethods();
    for (Method method:methods)
    {
        String name=method.getName();
        if(name.startsWith("get") || name.startsWith("is"))
        {
           //...code to remove the prefixes
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reflections API, POJO fields can be retrieved as below. Inherited class may find an issue here.

```
TestClass testObject= new TestClass().getClass();
Fields[] fields = testObject.getFields();
for (Field field:fields)
{
    String name=field.getName();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Or by using Reflections API, one can also retrieve all methods in a class and iterate through it to find the attribute names (standard POJO methods start with get/is/set) ... This approach worked for me for Inherited class structure.

```
TestClass testObject= new TestClass().getClass();
Method[] methods = testObject.getMethods();
for (Method method:methods)
{
    String name=method.getName();
    if(name.startsWith("get"))
    {
        System.out.println(name.substring(3));
    }else if(name.startsWith("is"))
    {
        System.out.println(name.substring(2));
    }
}
```

However a more interesting approach is below:

With the help of Jackson library, I was able to find all class properties of type String/integer/double, and respective values in a Map class. (*all without using reflections api!*)

```
TestClass testObject = new TestClass();
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper m = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();

Map<String,Object> props = m.convertValue(testObject, Map.class);

for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : props.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getValue() instanceof String || entry.getValue() instanceof Integer || entry.getValue() instanceof Double){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "-->" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should access through the method. At the moment the getter would return the member `name`, *but that could change in the future*. It could lazily instantiate this from a database or webservice, built it from a firstname/surname etc. The `name` field could quite likely not exist.

So always go through the method (even via reflection)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the method, you only need to remove "get" and convert to lower letter the following letter, so you don´t need reflection.

If the getter method (getName()) returns a property with different name than "name", you can´t obtain the property's name from the method´s name.

If you don´t know the name of the method, by reflection you can obtain all methods and you can obtain all name´s properties too.

Answer (score -3):

Try the following

```
class A{

       private String name;
       private String salary;

   //getter and setter methods

       public void setName(String name){
          this.name = name;
        }

       public void setSalary(String salary){
           this.salary = salary;

         }

        public String getName(){
          return name;
          }

        public String getSalary(){
          return salary;
          }
```

}

The **get** method is used to retrieve data dynamically from program method or from database. It will reflect only values not property of the value.