# Truncate string to be saved?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA. I need to trim the string before saving if its length is more than the column size. I have below code.

One can truncate a string according to the JPA annotations in the setter for the corresponding field:

```
public void setX(String x) {
    try {
        int size = getClass().getDeclaredField("x").getAnnotation(Column.class).length();
        int inLength = x.length();
        if (inLength>size)
        {
            x = x.substring(0, size);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
    }
    this.x = x;
}
```

The annotation itself should look like:

```
@Column(name = "x", length=100)
private String x;
```

Now my question is, I want above logic for many fields in many Entities. How can I write/make above logic to be generic to avoid duplicated code in all the entities for all the fields.

Comment: You may create your own annotation to do the work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Are there annotations with *active* code? Do I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @laune what do you mean by annotations with *active code*?

Comment: Not an answer, but this looks like a terrible idea to me. The last thing I'd want from a computer is to tell me that my 2000 characters story has been successfully accepted and saved, even though it only saved the first 100 characters and discarded the rest silently.

Comment: @JBNizet Add another field to the annotation: `boolean silent` and you can have it either way.

Comment: @laune if I always set silent to false, then I don't need any annotation, because the database driver will throw a SQLException automatically if the length is greater than the column length.

Comment: @JBNizet This is completely valid usecase. Say, you are storing self-descriptions of users, review comments about certain products, etc, where you are given a limit of 100 and user's input is 2000.. then discarding the rest silently completely makes sense. A bad usecase?.. maybe! but terrible idea.. NO! (just an opinion. might be wrong)

Comment: @karthikmanchala If user's input length is 2000, user should receive an error message (or even better: not be able to post at all), because the input can't be stored in the database. That's my whole point. If there is no user and I'm importing descriptions from a file or something, then this truncation should be handled in the business layer, not in the model.

Comment: @JBNizet exactly.. user should receive error message or not able to post at all.. and this should/can be handled at view layer itself by mapping model to the view (eg: field to textbox) without any extra efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for this, neither of which are going to be as hands-off as you'd like.

1. Use an aspect with the library org.Reflections.  I think this would have to be compile-time-with-aspectj, because you'd have to use Reflections to get all the fields that have the annotation, then figure out what setters belong to those fields, and then apply an aspect around those.
2. Have a static method that uses internal reflection and a line of code in each setter.

I tried the first path and it started to get to get too complicated, so I tried #2 and used something found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192734/getting-a-property-field-name-using-getter-method-of-a-pojo-java-bean/13514566).

```
public static String truncate(String string)
{
    try
    {
        final StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2];
        final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(stackTraceElement.getClassName());
        final BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz);
        final String methodName = stackTraceElement.getMethodName();
        final PropertyDescriptor[] props = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for(final PropertyDescriptor descriptor : props)
        {
            if(descriptor.getWriteMethod() != null)
            {
                if(methodName.equals(descriptor.getWriteMethod().getName()))
                {
                    System.out.println(descriptor.getDisplayName());
                    final Column annotation =
                            clazz.getDeclaredField(descriptor.getDisplayName()).getAnnotation(Column.class);
                    if(annotation != null)
                    {
                        final int size = annotation.length();
                        if(size == 255)
                        {
                            // Highly likely we hit the default value, which means nothing was specified so just
                            // move along
                        }
                        else if(string.length() > size)
                        {
                            string = string.substring(0, size);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(final IntrospectionException e)
    {
    }
    catch(final Exception e)
    {
    }

    return string;
}
```

You have a basic column definition

```
@Column(name = "personTitle", length = 5)
private String personTitle;
```

Then in the setter

```
public void setPersonTitle(final String personTitle)
{
    this.personTitle = JpaStringTruncator.truncate(personTitle);
}
```

This assumes that your setter is calling the static method so you only have to backtrack a few elements in the StackTrace.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I used is simply to define, in all entity classes, int variables that hold the max size of each String field and to use those variables in the setters to trim the strings if they exceed the size limit.

Since I generate my entity classes on the fly with Netbeans' `Entity classes from database` wizard, I needed an automated way to generate the int variables like those:

```
public static final int ID_NUMBER_SIZE = 16;
public static final int WEB_SITE_NAME_SIZE = 100;
public static final int WEB_URL_SIZE = 50;
```

So I wrote the following python script which parse all `*.java` files in a given directory and use a regex to match field definitions containing a `@Size` constraint.  The script is simply run by invoking it on the command line `py entities_size.py` and by refreshing the dispaly in your IDE (<kbd>F5</kbd> in Eclipse) as the source files were modified outside it.  If you first want to test the script, you  can comment out the last line which writes the changes to the files.

```
import os,glob,re
from pathlib import Path

path = 'C:\\users\\pierre\\git\\myProject\\backend\\src\\main\\java\\ca\\qc\\myDomain\\myApp\\entity'

# For each *.java file in the path above
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.java')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # Read each file
        contents = f.read()
        # Find all String variables' name and size with a regex
        varsAndSizesTuples = re.findall(r'@Size\(max\s*=\s*(\d+)[\s\S]*?(?=@Column\(name\s*=\s*\"(\w*)\")', contents, re.MULTILINE)
        newString = "\n"
        # Iterate over each variable and size to create the java code for a new int variable 
        # and accumulate those declarations in the newString variable
        for tuple in varsAndSizesTuples:
            newString = newString + "\tpublic static final int " + str(tuple[1]) + "_SIZE = " + str(tuple[0]) + ";\n"
        print(filename + "\n" + newString + "\n")
        # Finds the position of the class declaration with a regex
        index = re.compile(r"public class.*{[^}]").search(contents).end()
        # Inserts the new variables declaration right after the class declaration
        contents = contents[:index] + newString + contents[index:]
    # Write the changes to the file
    with open(filename, 'w') as f: f.write(contents)
```

The first regex `@Size\(max\s*=\s*(\d+)[\s\S]*?(?=@Column\(name\s*=\s*\"(\w*)\")` is used to extract both the field names and their size limits (test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZfYCtF/1), see below) while the second regex `public class.*{[^}]` is used to find the `public class` declaration to insert the new variables declarations after it.

[image]

Once this is done, I wrote the following static method to return the trimed string (if required).  Note that, for simplicity, the method doesn't test `null` or otherwise invalid arguments.

```
public static String trim(String string, int limit) {
    return string.substring(0, Math.min(string.length(), limit) - 1);
}
```

The method needs to be called on each setter with the string to validate and its size limit:

```
myEntity.setIdNumber(RefTblInit.trim(stringToPossiblyTrim, MyEntity.ID_NUMBER_SIZE));
```

This way I made sure my code wouldn't break because of setters' arguments exceeding their size limit.